# ng-if & ng-show failing to toggle visibility of table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the below angularJS code which was working fine up until yesterday. I have no idea why this isn't working the unresponsive angular tags {{ variable }} are not showing therefore I assume I'm connected to my ng app. As said nothing has changed my data source is retrieved by localhost successfully and I can see in developer tools that all the correct content is there. I've searched for any minor syntax errors and cant find any whatsoever I'm completely stumped as to why this isn't working.

## ng-app

```
var app = angular.module("viewJSON",[]);
app.controller("viewCtrl",function Hello($scope, $http) {
       $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './data.json'
        }).then(function (response){
            $scope.products = response.data;

        },function (error){
            console.log("error");
        });
    });
```

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="viewJSON">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="home-page.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="home-page.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="viewCtrl">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="search" ng-innit="x=0">
            <b>Product Name:</b> <input type="text" ng-model="searchName" class="searchTerm" ng-keydown="x = x+1"><br>
            <b>Product Brand:</b> <input type="text" ng-model="searchBrand" class="searchTerm" ng-keydown="x = x+1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="resultContent" ng-if="x > 0">

            <tr>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Retailer</th>
                <th>Image</th>
            </tr>

            <tr id="rows" ng-repeat="item in products" ng-if="searchName.length != 0 && searchBrand.length != 0" ng-show="item.name.includes(searchName) && item.brand.includes(searchBrand)">
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.brand }}</td>
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.price }}</td>
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.retailer }}</td>
                <td class="imageCol"><img ng-src="{{ item.image_url}}"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried putting the script at the bottom of the page just above the closing body tag, as stated previously I believe angular is responsive as im not seeing any {{ x }} tags on my web page. The data parses to the js object without raising the error exception also. As said the code was working fine yesterday, could this be something to do with my localhost configuration or am I missing something obvious.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? That would be the first thing I would look for. Also, chuck a console.log in your .then() to see your output of $scope.products.

You could also try emitting the ng-if to see if that's what is stopping the data from being show,

Comment: Missed that detail in my question. Console doesn't throw any errors. Ill test the output now.

Comment: I think one of the issues maybe related to the ng-src - it's been a while but I think when you use any type of ng-* you don't need {{ this }}

Comment: Everything outputs fine after the console.log and all json keys match the parameters specified in the html angular tags

Comment: ng-src was working fine yesterday which tells me its not that, although I'll have a google now to explore that possibility

Comment: Did you try removing the ng-if? You have ng-if x > 0... What is x?

Comment: x is defined with ng-innit in the div tag for the search bar. On key-down x increments by one so the data will only show if a user has presented an input.

Comment: You have a typo in ng-init. You have it as ng-innit - could that be it?

Comment: hahaha that's the one thank you for your help

Comment: Not using an object in `ng-model` is **bad**. Especially considering all the child scopes you create with nested `ng-if` combined with `ng-repeat`.  Also having `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` and `ng-show` all on same element could be streamlined to filtering logic on `items`

Comment: I'll take this into account and have look at more efficient ways to do this

Comment: No worries bro! I remember the days of playing with angular 1 and not knowing anything at all. Heck, I started a degree in business! Keep at it mate, the more you learn the more you enjoy it. Also, remember to give back to the community where you can :)

I would also advise you to move away from angular1 when your ready and move over to vue.js, react or angular 2+. Only when your ready... But it will keep you in much better stead moving forwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your 'ng-innit', replace this with 'ng-init'.